# PHP variable to string in html

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm new in php:

```
$link = bloginfo("stylesheet_directory");

'before_title' => 

'<h3 class="widget"><img class="image-left" src="(HERE VARIABLE) + /images/svg/custom-header-left.svg">'
```

The quick question - how put `$link` variable to this image src and add to it `/images/svg/custom-header-left.svg`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy, close the string and concatenate using the string concatenation operator `.`.

```
$link = bloginfo("stylesheet_directory");

'before_title' => 

'<h3 class="widget"><img class="image-left" src="' . $link . '/images/svg/custom-header-left.svg">'
```

Comment: ok my problem was using $link = bloginfo() and not $link = get_bloginfo() ... but this was right answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can concatenate with `.`:

```
'<h3 class="widget"><img class="image-left" src="' . $link . '/images/svg/custom-header-left.svg">'
```

Or you could declare your string with double quotes `"` and just interpolate `$link`:

```
"<h3 class=\"widget\"><img class=\"image-left\" src=\"$link/images/svg/custom-header-left.svg\">"
```